# How to query SOLR for emtpy fields of the fieldType LatLonPointSpatialField

Tags: solr, lucene

I have the following fieldType:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonPointSpatialField" docValues="true"/>
```

and defined the following field:

```
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

How can i query for an empty location field?

Comment: If the field is not present at all, `*:* -location:[* TO *]` should work. Otherwise, what's the actual content of the field?

Comment: I get an error 500 when I try this query

The actual content of the field is currently an empty string "", but I can easily change this so that the field is not present at all.

Comment: The Solr log should show a reason when you get a 500 - but dropping the field is usually far better, as it shows intent and doesn't waste resources index an empty value.